# how to add TXT file to the sub folder of war. i.e I wants to add key.txt to the WEB-INF

Tags: java, jar, war, vs-web-application-project

For this Normally I used the command `jar uvf app.war c:/key.txt`
This command copy `key.txt` file to the app.war folder.
But I want, Key should copy to the sub folder of the `app.war`.
For example after unzipping app/WEB-INF/key.txt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add a java class to a folder within a jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044243/how-to-add-a-java-class-to-a-folder-within-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create directory `WEB-INF` beside war archive and put there your file `key.txt`.
Then simply execute `jar uvf app.war WEB-INF/key.txt`

Reference: [Updating a JAR File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html)

Comment: its giving me an error no such file or directory found and

Comment: Its giving me error adding : WEB-INF/key.txt<in = 34><out = 26><deflected 23%>

Comment: That's not an error, that's the detail about the added file you asked for with 'v'. And the algorithm is deflated not deflected.