# Include a class file into a JAR file

Tags: java

Can anyone please tell me how to add a class file into particular package inside a JAR file using command prompt.

Example: Test.jar has a packaging structure com.test
Now I want to add a class file called Test.class into com.test package of Test.jar file.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add a java class to a folder within a jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044243/how-to-add-a-java-class-to-a-folder-within-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can update a JAR file by passing the 'u' argument and supplying the JAR and file you want to add:

```
jar uf Test.jar com/test/Test.class
```

More info about this option [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
jar uf jar-file input-file(s)
```

In this command:

```
The u option indicates that you want to update an existing JAR file.
The f option indicates that the JAR file to update is specified on the command line.
jar-file is the existing JAR file that's to be updated.
input-file(s) is a space-delimited list of one or more files that you want to add to the Jar file.
Any files already in the archive having the same pathname as a file being added will be overwritten.
```

Ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html